# How can I extract email addresses from a Group?

Tags: groups

I've created a Group of individuals and I would now like to extract all of their email addresses.  Is there a way to do this? When I view the list of individuals in the Group I can partially view the email addresses but not the full addresses. I've set the Group up so we have a list of our current donors and I want to email them but not via CiviCRM.

Answer (score 2):

After you perform a search or show the contacts in a group, you can select all contacts and go to **Actions > Export Contacts**.

[image]

On the next screen, choose which fields you want to export with the contacts or just select "Export PRIMARY fields." Then hit "Continue" and a save dialog box will pop up and save it as a .csv which you can import into a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can export Email addresses of all Types using the fields option (where you get to select specific fields you need in the export);

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/exporting-your-contacts/